# How come escape velocity isn't imaginary?

Tags: gravity, escape-velocity

There's gotta be a simple explaination for this.  Going through several definitions, it appears that escape velocity is equal to the potential energy.  That is:$$\frac{1}{2}m v^2=-\frac{G M m}{r}$$but if I solve for velocity, $v$, I get:$$v=\sqrt{-2\frac{G M}{r}}$$So how do I get an escape velocity that isn't imaginary?

Comment: Escape velocity isn't equal to gravitational potential energy. It is equal to the *difference* between the gravitational potential energy at infinity (ie. zero) and the expression you quote.

Comment: Are you saying escape velocity is $\frac{1}{2}m v^2=0 - \frac{G M m}{r}$

Comment: he means to say $$\frac{1}{2}m v^2=0-(-\frac{G M m}{r})$$

Comment: @DominicGuana It *is* what I said.

Comment: @RobJeffries yes exactly

Answer (score 5):

Escape velocity isn't equal to gravitational potential energy. It is equal to the difference between the gravitational potential energy at infinity (ie. zero) and the expression you quote.
$$ \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = 0 - \left(-\frac{GMm}{r}\right)$$

Better still, think about it in terms of the total energy (kinetic and potential) being the same when the object is launched from the surface and when it comes to rest at infinity.
$$ \frac{1}{2}mv^2 -\frac{GMm}{r} = 0 + 0$$

Comment: I like Eq. 2 b/c it aligns more closely with how conservation laws are taught.